# The Span of a Kernel and the span of an Image

Tags: linear-algebra

I have recently been set a question on Linear Algebra and I just cannot wrap my head around the concept of Kernels and Images etc.

If someone could show me how to do this question and explain why I would really appreciate it.

A is a linear map such that $ A: \mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3} $ with A defined as :

$$ A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Describe the Kernel as $ Ker(A) \subset \mathbb{R^4} $ and the image $ Im(A) \subset \mathbb{R^3} $ by writing each as a span of linearally independant vectors.

Thanks guys...

Comment: Can you give the definition of "kernel" and "image" in words?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel is set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ mapping to the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ under $A$. It is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as you should verify. The image is the set of vectors $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ which are mapped onto from $\mathbb{R}^4$ under $A$. It is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, as you should again verify. Hence, both $\text{Ker}(A)$ and $\text{Im}(A)$ have a basis in $\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively (i.e. a linearly independent spanning set).

I won't do your exact problem for you, but I'll give you an example of how we would go about finding bases for the kernel and image of some linear transformation. Let $A:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $A(x,y)=x$. That is, $A$ is the projection map onto the first coordinate from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}$. For the kernel we want to find the set of vectors $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ so $Ax=0$. Clearly $Ax=0$ precisely when $x=0$ ($y$ can be anything). So the kernel is the set of all vectors $(x,y)$ with $x=0$. This is clearly spanned by $v=(0,1)$, and $v=(0,1)$ is clearly linearly independent. For the image, we note that if I take $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x$ is mapped onto by $(x,y)$ under $A$. And so the image of our linear transformation is everything in $\mathbb{R}$, and so it suffices to exhibit a basis for $\mathbb{R}$. Simply take the basis $v=1$ which is again linearly independent and we are done.

Since your $A$ is not quite so nice as the dummy $A$ I defined, you will need to do a little more work by playing around with your matrix (i.e. row-reducing) to get your result. But this is the idea of kernel and image.